# Why does the AddGeometryColumn function not exist in RSQLite?

Tags: r, sqlite, spatialite-gui

I am trying to add the geometry to a new table with the following statement:

```r
library(RSQLite)
# db.sqlite was created with spatialite-gui
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname  = "C:/GIS/db.sqlite") 

rs <- dbSendQuery(con, 
  "CREATE TABLE test_geom (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL
      PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    measured_value DOUBLE NOT NULL);")
dbClearResult(rs)

rs <- dbSendQuery(con,
"SELECT AddGeometryColumn('test_geom', 'Geometry', 4326, 'POINT', 'XY');")
```

But it generates the following error:

```
Error: no such function: AddGeometryColumn
```

If I execute the same statement in **spatialite-gui** if it works.

Comment: Does the RSQLite library claim to implement every statement in spatiallite-gui?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R is using the SQLite driver to access the file, so its equivalent to reading the database using `sqlite3` instead of `spatialite`:

```
$ sqlite3 spatial.sqlite 'select AddGeometryColumn()'
Error: no such function: AddGeometryColumn


$ spatialite spatial.sqlite -cmd 'select AddGeometryColumn()'
spatialite: Error: too many options: "select AddGeometryColumn()"
```

A database opened with `sqlite3` will have all the tables for a spatial database but won't have the functions because those are only available when opened using a spatialite driver. RSQLite only uses the base sqlite3 code.

What you need to do is load the spatialite module into sqlite.

Starting with a non-spatial connection:

```
> library(RSQLite)
> con = dbConnect(SQLite(),"./spatial.sqlite")
> dbSendQuery(con,"select AddGeometryColumn()")
Error: no such function: AddGeometryColumn
```

You need to find the path to your spatialite module. On Linux that's a `.so` file, which I've found here `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mod_spatialite.so` - then I can load that using `load_extension`:

```
> dbSendQuery(con,"select load_extension('/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mod_spatialite.so');")
<SQLiteResult>
  SQL  select load_extension('/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mod_spatialite.so');
  ROWS Fetched: 0 [incomplete]
       Changed: 0
```

Now when I see if this connection has `AddGeometryColumns`:

```
> dbSendQuery(con,"select AddGeometryColumn()")
Error: wrong number of arguments to function AddGeometryColumn()
In addition: Warning message:
Closing open result set, pending rows
```

It jolly well does.

I think under Windows you need to find a .dll file.

Figured most of this out from https://github.com/pschmied/RSQLite.spatialite which is very old and crashed my R. But the principles are outlined there.

Comment: I downloaded the dll from http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/windows-bin-amd64/ but  he doesn't recognize it. 
`> file.exists("C:/GIS/sqlite/mod_spatialite.dll")`
`[1] TRUE`
`> dbSendQuery(con,"select load_extension('C:/GIS/sqlite/mod_spatialite.dll');")`
`Error: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.`

Comment: Hmmm see if you can get it working from an `sqlite3` command line. Try it without the ".dll" part... Really not a windows expert so not sure what I can do...